# Translate to multiple languages at once in WhisperAI?

Tags: openai-whisper

Essentially the title. I need to translate recordings into over twenty different languages (long reason), and I was wondering if I could do them all at once and step away from my computer. If not, it is ok, but it would be nice considering I have to do this for many recordings.